# View ArcGIS 10 metadata in SharePoint 2010

Tags: arcgis-10.0, metadata, xml

Does anyone know how I can view the "FGDC CSDGM"-compliant metadata in SharePoint 2010?
I know I can copy the metadata output since it's an html file but that's not what I want. I want SharePoint 2010 to be able to view the metadata, or GENERATE it itself, if possible, using the xsl/xslt stylesheets in ArcGIS 10. In other words, I want to "plug in" SharePoint with ArcGIS/ArcCatalog to see 'real-time' metadata.

So this leads to my other question, does anyone know the process by which ArcCatalog 10 uses different stylesheets (there are so many) to ultimately create the final output (dhtml) which we see in ArcCatalog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would just implement a web page or web part in SharePoint that uses the Javascript API.. ESRI have a lot of examples here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm

Answer (score 1):

[ArcGIS Mapping for Sharepoint](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/mapping-sharepoint/download.html) offers what you're looking for (may be with a little customization).

Cheers!